# PHP ZipArchive: replace formatted text in .docx?

Tags: php, linux, command-line, ms-word

I'm trying to replace some strings with other strings in my `docx` file, like it's described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47130421).

Everything works fine with non-formatted text, but bold text I want to replace gets ignored. Is it somehow possible using just native `ZipArchive`, or should I abandon the hope and install something additional?

Linux command line would be fine too, but `sed` has same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was more a search pattern question. Strings I wanted to replace had some wicked formatting like `%username%` and `{{date}}`, replacing them with simple `NAME` and `DATE` made everything work just fine